# Simple rotation transformation problem

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm trying to do a very simple thing but it doesn't work well....
I drew the axes (XYZ)
Then I did the following:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glPushMatrix();

glRotated( 45 , 1 , 0 , 0 );//around X
glRotated(-45 , 0 , 1 , 0); //around Y 

glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glVertex3d(0,0,0);
  glVertex3d( 1,1,1);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

But somehow the line I draw (1,1,1) isn't drawn exactly on the Z axis....
Can someone tell me why?

Update:

So what i understand is that openGL rotates the scene with glRotated( 45 , 1 , 0 , 0 ) hence the Y axis is not at 0 , 1 , 0 anymore hence the next operation glRotated( -45 , 0 , 1 , 0 ) will not make the rotation around the "original" Y axis. am i correct?

Let me tell you what i need to do:
I get a plane by the equation Ax+By+Cz+D = 0 from the user and i need to draw this plane on the screen.
So what i had i maind is to draw an infinate plane on XY and then roate+translate him to his right place. 
i meant to move the plane to his place by unifying the Z axis with his normal.
can someone give me the 3 right operation: rotate+rotate+translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rotated axes are not at the same angles to the original (reference) plane, so vector `(1,1,1)` won't point directly "up". Your original Y axis is at th 45 degree angle after the first (and second) rotation, but your original Z and X axes are not. They indeed lay in plane which is 45 degrees to the original, but on that plane only two terminal directions make 45 degree angle, which is not the case for your Z and X after second rotation.
You should try to use 60 degrees in first rotation, an 45 degrees in second. This way all axes will be at 30 degree angle to the reference plane, and vector `(1,1,1)` will point directly up.

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct. You can see this as follows:

Your line starts out as the diagonal in a cube with edges parallel to the coordinate axes. If you take a plane through one axis, and at a 45 degree angle to the others, its intersection with the cube is a rectangle, but not a square -- one side of the rectangle (parallel to a coordinate axis) is an edge of the cube, but the other is a face diagonal whose length is the square root of two. Your line is the diagonal of this rectangle, so its angle with the sides is not 45 degrees -- which it would have to be for your construction to align it exactly to the Z axis.